# CaffeineCache is not refreshed immediately after put operation in Spring Boot application

Tags: spring-boot, caching, caffeine, caffeine-cache

I have a random issue with `CaffeineCache` in my Spring Boot application. The problem is with an integration test that makes next

- find user
- delete it
- find it again

It seems that sometimes cache doesn't not refreshes on time before the second call of `find` that comes immediately after delete.

Here is a simplified signature of `find` method

```
@Cacheable(cacheNames = "name", key = "{#config.id, #userId}", unless = "#result == null")
public User find(SomeConfig config, String userId) { 
     // ... 
}
```

And a simplified signature of delete

```
@Caching(put = {
        @CachePut(cacheNames = "someOtherCache", key = "#userId.technicalId"),
        @CachePut(cacheNames = "name", key = "{#config.id, #userId}")
})
public User delete(SomeConfig config, String userId)  { 
     // ... 
}
```

I suppose that after call `delete` cache is not updated immediately and that's why method `find` is not called the second time. It happens 1 times from 10.

Any ideas about fix?